# Difference between true & 1 and false & 0

Tags: c++, boolean

When assigning a value to a `bool`, we have 2 options:

```
bool b = true;
```

```
bool b = 1;
```

Now my question is are these 2 any different in `C++`? And what's better to use?

Comment: Both are valid options supported by the standard. Using the value of `true` is unambiguous and clearer overall to the reader than the latter.

Comment: Actually, you can count on 0 (zero) being `false`.  Any value that is **not zero** is `true`.

Comment: `bool b = 1;` uses a conversion from `int` to `bool`; same as `bool b = 42;`. `bool b = true` uses the right type.

Comment: If you assign any non-zero value to a `bool`, `bool b = 42`, for example, the conversion of integer to `bool` changes its value internally in the `bool` to 1. So after `bool b = 42`, the check `b == 1` will be true. As mentioned by @jrd1 using `true` and `false` as the values is the best, unambiguous approach. I personally don't like counting on the internal representation of `true`. In addition, instead of checking `if (b == true)` you can just use `if (b)` or instead of `if (b == false)` you can just use `if (! b)`. That shorter form is/can also be used to check for non-zero or zero value.

Comment: @lurker -- re: "changes its value internally in the `bool` to 1" -- no, it changes the value of the `bool` to `true`. There is no requirement that `true` be represented by 1, nor that `false` be represented by 0. When a `bool` value is converted to an integer value, `false` becomes 0 and `true` becomes 1. Yes, the check `b == 1` is true; also, `b == 42` is true; and `b == 0` is false. But that's because of conversions, not because of the internal representation. (yes, every implementation I know of uses 0 and 1, but that's an implementation detail, not a requirement)

Comment: @PeteBecker I didn't express it correctly. Thank you for the correction. My primary point was that the behavior of `true` for a `bool` is as a 1 if compared or output as an `int` or even as `cout << boolValue`. When I had commented on a different question that the comparison `if (b == 1)` (where `b` is s `bool`) was "improper" to check for true, I was scolded by another C++ programmer and told that it was fine. However, I still don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: @lurker -- "don't think it's a good idea" -- I agree completely.

Comment: There are many more options, like `bool b = 123;`, or `bool b = "false";`, or `bool b = 3.14;`, or ...